# Tkinter grid layout won't expand

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.4

I'm trying to design sidebar which should looke like most of Google's sidebar menu (like in Inbox or Play Music, browser version, for example).
I'm using the grid layout but it won't expand. I've looked it up a little bit and despite adding `sticky = "nesw"` and `rowconfigure(0, weigth = 1)`, the frame on the right won't expand and fill the root.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

buttons = ["Button", "Button", "Button", "Button", "Button", "Button", "Button", "Button", "Button", "Button"]  # List of contacts

root = Tk()
root.title('MyApp v0.1')
root.geometry('800x600')
#root['bg'] = "white"

# Side menu
frame = Frame(root, background = "white")
for i in range(len(buttons)):
    Button(frame, background = "white", text = buttons[i], command = None).grid(row = i, column = 0)
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nesw")

sep = ttk.Separator(root, orient = "vertical")
sep.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
sep.columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)
sep.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 5, sticky = "nesw")

root.mainloop()
```

Here's what I get. My buttons on the left are supposed to be on a white background Frame. The Frame and the separator should go down to the bottom of the application window.

[image: Result display]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want the Buttons' container to stretch all the way from the top of the window to the bottom, try calling `rowconfigure` on the root. And if you want the buttons to be evenly distributed, rather than calling `frame.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)`, call `frame.rowconfigure` for *each* row of the frame from 0 to `len(buttons)`.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

buttons = ["Button", "Button", "Button", "Button", "Button", "Button", "Button", "Button", "Button", "Button"]  # List of contacts

root = Tk()
root.title('MyApp v0.1')
root.geometry('800x600')
#root['bg'] = "white"
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

# Side menu
frame = Frame(root, background = "white")
for i in range(len(buttons)):
    Button(frame, background = "white", text = buttons[i], command = None).grid(row = i, column = 0)
    frame.rowconfigure(i, weight = 1)
frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nesw")

sep = ttk.Separator(root, orient = "vertical")
sep.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
sep.columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)
sep.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 5, sticky = "nesw")
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: this is true but bad practice, what if I had 2 layers inside the root and I just want the last one to be stretched to bottom while not pulling the first one?